# Google's new recaptcha not validating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, forms-authentication, form-submit, recaptcha

Am I missing something?  I copied this code snippet over:

[Automatically render the reCAPTCHA widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render)

I entered my registered data-sitekey.  The reCAPTCHA displays and works when I check the box, but if I don't check the box and submit my form, the reCAPTCHA doesn't stop the user submission and my controller processes the request.

```
@model Medicaid.WebUI.ViewModels.RequestModel

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "request-form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        { 
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         <fieldset>
          <legend>Request</legend>
           <div class="form-group">
             <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name</label>
             <div class="col-lg-10">
               <input type="text" value="@Model.FirstName" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="inputLastName" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
               <input type="text" value="@Model.LastName" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="LastName" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
               </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input type="email" value="@Model.Email" class="form-control" maxlength="100" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2"><br /><br />
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="IenterMykeyHere"></div><br /><br />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Request</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><br />
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this issue and re-read the documentation, and worked it out as the following:

```
function onBegin() {
    $("input[type='hidden']").val(grecaptcha.getResponse());
}
```

You have to add a javascript function to the "onBegin" parameter of the AjaxOptions object from the MVC html helper - that will copy the value of the widget's response to a hidden variable you need to declare inside your form, so the submit button sends it to the controller. Don't forget to add a variable with the same name to the "RequestModel" view model so that the mvc model-binding passes it and you then will be able, in the server, to know if the user has clicked the button or not.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewRecaptchaVerify", "ReCaptcha", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
    OnFailure = "onFailure",
    OnBegin = "onBegin",
    OnComplete = "onComplete"
}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Response)
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your-site-key"></div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
}
```

(for the record, I am now facing the problem of knowing, in the server, in cases where the widget prompted the user to enter a text input, after clicking the button - whether he/she entered the text or not. Seems to me that in the end I will have no way out other than performing a GET request, in the server, to the widget's api, as they put it in the documentation: `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=your_secret&response=response_string&remoteip=user_ip_address`